# Ubuntu Terminal server for Windows clients

Tags: server

We plan to provide internet access for production users in a secure way with a terminal server.

I need suggestions on how to create a Ubuntu terminal server for minimal application us like Firefox that can be accessed by RDP form Windows 7 computer.

Setting up a Windows terminal server and the like would not make sense considering the costs just to provide internet access.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to internet cafe. Would setting up a kisok-system be a possible alternative? http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/07/create-ubuntu-kiosk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options. You can use xrdp for this, which would be available to the built-in rdp-client in Windows. An easier solution, that also probably provides a better experience, is X2go. However, this requires an application to be installed on the client. There's also Nomachine NX, which is the upstream for X2go.